# How to add numbers in a string

Tags: python

Im new to python and i have a homework to validate a credit card number. I finished the first two conditions but Im stucked with #3 and #4 conditions. Any help is appreciated

Conditions:

1. The first digit must be a 4.- done
2. The fourth digit must be one greater than the fifth digit; keep in mind that these are separated by a dash since the format is ####-####-####.-done
3. The sum of all digits must be evenly divisible by 4.-need help
4. If you treat the first two digits as a two-digit number, and the seventh and eighth digits
   as a two-digit number, their sum must be 100.- need help

```
def verify(number) : # do not change this line!

  # write your code here so that it verifies the card number
  #condtion 1  
  if number[0] != '4':
    return "violates rule #1"

  #condition 2
  if int(number[3]) != (int(number[5]) + 1) :
    return  "violates rule #2"

  #condition 3
  for i in number:
    if i >= '0' and i !='-':

  # be sure to indent your code!

  return True # modify this line as needed

input = "4037-6000-0000" # change this as you test your function
output = verify(input) # invoke the method using a test input
print(output) # prints the output of the function
# do not remove this line!
```

Expected outputs:

```
● "5000-0000-0000": violates rule #1
● "4000-0000-0000": passes rule #1, violates rule #2
● "4007-6000-0000": passes rules #1-2, violates rule #3
● "4037-6000-0000": passes rules #1-3, violates rule #4
● “4094-3460-2754”: passes all rules
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: use a modulo for divisibility..based on condition 2 you should already know how to access the numbers for condition 4 and add them together

Answer (score 0):

For rule 3, you need to sum all the numbers and the check if the remainder on division by 4 is zero:

```
  #condition 3
  s = 0
  for i in number:
    if i != '-':
      s += int(i)
  if s % 4 != 0:
    return "violates rule #3"
```

For rule 4 you can get the sum of int of substrings:

```
if (int(number[0:2]) + int(number[7:8])) != 100:
    return "violates rule #4"
```

Full code :

```
def verify(number) : # do not change this line!

  # write your code here so that it verifies the card number
  #condtion 1  
  if number[0] != '4':
    return "violates rule #1"

  #condition 2
  if int(number[3]) != (int(number[5]) + 1) :
    return  "violates rule #2"

  #condition 3
  s = 0
  for i in number:
    if i != '-':
      s += int(i)
  if s % 4 != 0:
    return "violates rule #3"

  if (int(number[0:2]) + int(number[7:9])) != 100:
    return "violates rule #4"

  # be sure to indent your code!
  return True # modify this line as needed

input = "4037-6000-0000" # change this as you test your function
output = verify(input) # invoke the method using a test input
print(output) # prints the output of the function
# do not remove this line!
```

Comment: should be int(number[7]) and 8

Comment: indexing is from 0 in python so i guess 6 and 7 for 7th and 8th position is right

Comment: `int(number[0])*10+int(number[1])+int(number[6])*10+int(number[7])`

Comment: there's a dash in the string that takes a place

Answer (score 0):

For condition #3

Strings in Python are iterable meaning you can pass over them in a `for` loop. Each element in the loop is a character in the string. So if you did

```py
for char in "4094-3460-2754":
    print(char)
```

You'd get:

```py
4
0
9
4
-
3
4
etc.
```

Using this, you can calculate the sum of every number in the input and check if it's divisible by 4. Two things to note, you need to convert the characters to integers first (using `int`). You can't do

```py
"4" + "0"
```

But you can do

```py
int("4") + int("0")
```

You'll need to exclude "-" from your sum as well using `if`.

Second, we check if two numbers are divisible in Python using modulo (`%`). The result is the remainder, and if the remainder is 0 then the first argument is divisible by the second.

```py
16 % 4 == 0 # divisible by 4
21 % 4 == 1 # not divisible by 4
```

For condition #4

In addition to being iterable, strings in Python can be accessed by their index (starting at 0)

```py
"4094-3460-2754"[0] == "4"
"4094-3460-2754"[1] == "0"
"4094-3460-2754"[2] == "9"
"4094-3460-2754"[0:1] == "40"
"4094-3460-2754"[1:2] == "09"
```

So you can access multiple characters and treat them as an integer:

```py
int("4094-3460-2754"[0:1]) == 40
```

Now you can add them together and see if they equal 100.

Answer (score 0):

> The sum of all digits must be evenly divisible by 4.

You can check this with a conditional statement like:

```
if sum_of_nums % 4 != 0:
   print("Violates rule 3!")
```

This checks if there is any remainder when dividing by four, and if there is no remainder it will divide evenly and the expression will equal zero. If it does not divide evenly it will not equal 0!

> If you treat the first two digits as a two-digit number, and the seventh and eighth digits as a two-digit number, their sum must be 100.

Here you can reference the characters of a string like you do a list. If the input is always going to be consistent you can hard code the references, change them to ints and then add them together and check them with a conditional statement

```
first_num = input[0]+input[1]
first_num = int(first_num) #now an int

second_num = input[6]+input[7]
second_num = int(second_num)

if first_num + second_num != 100:
   print("Violates rule 4!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer removing the dashes `-` from the number first so that it can be easy to work with. You can also do it without removing it like you tried.

```
# split it into parts separated by dashes
# consider 4094-3460-2754
no_dashes = number.split('-')

print(no_dashes) # ['4094', '3460', '2754']

# combine the numbers without dashes
no_dashes = ''.join(no_dashes)

print(no_dashes) # 409434602754

# convert it into a list of integers so that it is more easier to work with
number = [int(x) for x in no_dashes]

print(number) # [4, 0, 9, 4, 3, 4, 6, 0, 2, 7, 5, 4]
```

You can read about `split()` and `join()` [here](https://realpython.com/python-string-split-concatenate-join/).

Now, as you mentioned, the first condition is simple and you can simply check if the first number is 4 or not.

```
# 1st condition
if number[0] != 4:
    return 'Violates #1'
```

The second condition is also simple:

```
# 2nd condition
# 4th digit is a[3] and 5th digit is a[4]
if number[3] != number[4] + 1:
    return 'Viloates #2'
```

For the third condition, you just have to find the sum of every digit in the number. Since, we already converted the number into an integer array, this is also easy using the `sum()` function:

```
# 3rd condition
# Find the sum
num_sum = sum(number)

print(num_sum) # 48

# now check if the sum is divisible by 4
if num_sum % 4 != 0:
    return 'Violates #3'
```

Now, for the fourth condition, you need to treat the 1st & 2nd digit as a two-digit number and same with the 7th and 8th digit. You can convert it into two-digit number as follows:

```
# 1st digit is number[0]
# 2nd digit is number[1]
# 7th digit is number[6]
# 8ty digit is number [7]

# convert 1st two digits into a two-digit number
x = number[0] * 10 + number[1]

# convert 7th and 8th digits into a two-digit number
y = number[6] * 10 + number[7]
```

Now you can check if their sum is 100 or not:

```
 if x + y != 100:
     return 'Violates #4'
```

So, the combined program becomes (with some steps merged):

```
def verify(number):
    number = [int(x) for x in ''.join(number.split('-'))]

    if number[0] != 4:
        return 'Violates #1'

    if number[3] != number[4] + 1:
        return 'Viloates #2'

    if sum(number) % 4 != 0:
        return 'Violates #3'

    if (number[0] * 10 + number[1] + number[6] * 10 + number[7]) != 100:
        return 'Violates #4'

    return True
```

But the above program will only give the 1st condition that fails. You can modify it further if you want as follows:

```
def verify(number):
    failed = []
    number = [int(x) for x in ''.join(number.split('-'))]

    if number[0] != 4:
        failed += [1]

    if number[3] != number[4] + 1:
        failed += [2]

    if sum(number) % 4 != 0:
        failed += [3]

    if (number[0] * 10 + number[1] + number[6] * 10 + number[7]) != 100:
        failed += [4]

    res = 'Violates ' + (', '.join[str(x) for x in failed])

    return res if len(failed) != 0 else 'Passed'

print(verify('4094-3460-2754')) # Passed
print(verify('4037-6000-0000')) # Violates 4
```

You can again modify it to display passed conditions too. I leave it upto you!